# android stuck adding extra tab to fragment

Tags: android

currently has 2 fragments and i want to add one for now  i spent hours trying to figure out how to add it am lost , here is the code i have of the mainactivity.

```
public class SalaatTimesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Constants,



  }
}
```

the tab shows up but soon as i click 2nd or 3rd tab it crashes.

```
03-16 21:27:46.203  32749-32749/com.alimuzaffar.ramadanalarm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.alimuzaffar.ramadanalarm, PID: 32749
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.alimuzaffar.ramadanalarm.widget.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:122)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
            at com.alimuzaffar.ramadanalarm.widget.SlidingTabLayout$TabClickListener.onClick(SlidingTabLayout.java:328)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the line **FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:127)**

```
   fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        mFragments.set(position, fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment);

        return fragment;
    }
```

**frag2.class**

```
     import android.app.Fragment;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


public class fragtwo extends Fragment  {

  Location mLastLocation;
  MapFragment mMapFragment;
  GoogleMap mMap;

  //  private float currentDegree = 0f;
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;

  private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
  private float[] mValues = new float[3];

  private boolean mRegistered = false;
  private static boolean sWriterExternalPermissionDenied;

  public fragtwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }



  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

    }
  }



  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


    return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to add a 3rd tab? From what your adapter code says, you don't have an item if `position == 2`: This is causing a null item to be given, and so the viewpager is likely crashing because it's trying to instantiate a null fragment.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  switch (position) {
    case 0:

    case 1:
      return mKaabaLocatorFragment = KaabaLocatorFragment.newInstance(mLastLocation);
    case 2:
  }
  return null;
}
```

Add `return new fragtwo();` to case 2 and you should be set.

Comment: Hi fire3galaxy ah i se just to test if it crashes i added  below  case2 : the line from case1: it changes fragments but its not changing it to the fragment.class i want ,  in case 2: how do i open a fragment class

Comment: i created a new fragment class and layout and i want to call that new layout from case 2;

Comment: Which fragment do you want to open? The first, second, and 3rd tab are probably all the same, right?

Comment: 1st and 2nd different and its working when i currently click the 3rd one i get same layout as the 1st one , i want to open the 3rd one  ,  imy 3rd frag is named   fragtwo.class  and fragtwo.xml  , i want to create new layouts with its own stuff on them rather then have all tabs containing same things.  from case 2: i need to open the new fragtwo.class but not fully i want it to remain in the tab design view rather then having it open in full view mode

Comment: The reason I suspect they're all the same is because you didn't return a different fragment for case 0 in the method `getItem()`. Since there are no `break` statements in your code, the execution would just keep going and case 1's return statement would run. So you'd get Kaabalocatorfragment for both 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you create a fragment newInstance method for your fragtwo class like you did for kaabalocatorfragment? or a constructor if you don't need arguments to that fragment?

Comment: main problem is i dont know how to open the fragment calling it ,  for example   to open an activity without fragment it uses intent  method to call the class ,   but this project is using fragment so i dont know how to call class to  open

Comment: 0 which is tab1 is fine ,,,,  0 which is tab2 is fine  ,,, now i added ( 3 )  look just at the code right at the bottom just above if statment i added number 3 for 3 tabs , also on if statement i assigned  a title for it also which is information.

Comment: Can I see your fragtwo class code? Also, you can remove the java code for viewpager, that is not necessary

Comment: ok, try adding `return new fragtwo()` to `getItem()` for case 2. Btw, can I see a picture of what tab 0 and 1 look like?

Comment: Ooops sorry  try take a look at the edited code above frag2.class sir my apologies.          tab0 has  Large text that says ( Main )     tab2  has google maps ,  tab3 i added only 1 button

Comment: OMG OMG i love u i love you @FIRE3GALAXY  i love you boss your life saver boss i owe you one big time boss your a good hearted man love your spirit  you saved me bosss  i love you heheh  am happy now  this code you gave    return new fragtwo();  i added on   case 2:  and it worked  omg  now  my tab3 shows with 1 button weee hee thanks fire love u sir!!!

Comment: You're welcome. And wow, man. Praise God. I'm going to add this to the above solution now for future people.